# Mail Sending problem with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, smtp

I want to send a mail with through ASP.Net.But,that's gives me "SendUsing" error.

Code:

```
<%
string strKime = "xxx@hot.com";
string strKimden = "deneme@hot.com";
string strKonu = "ASP.net mail gönderme işlemi";
string strMetin = "Bu sayfa asp.net mail komponenti     tarafından gönderildi";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(strKimden, strKime, strKonu, strMetin);

%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, SMTP Server is not configured correctly? it is recommended that we always specify the definite smtpserver names for when calling the System.Web.Mail components or CDO.

Not sure if you are using this directly in the markup. Ideally, you should have a common code that sends emails taking the required parameters. Check out the link in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `SMTP` settings in the `web.config` file?

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network 
         host="ServerHostname" 
         port="portNumber"
         userName="username"
         password="password" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Email sending requires `SMTP` settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the SmtpClient Host property to the "mail.hot.com" or the ip of your outgoing mail server.